How to insert Ansible variables content into a CSV file?
I want the content held in 2 variables inserted into a CSV file each in a separate column but both variables insert their content into the same column.
I have tried this playbook
- name: "fetch remote host data"
  hosts: "redhat"

  tasks:

    - name: fetch user list
      shell: |
        awk -F: '{print $1}' /etc/passwd
      register: user_data

    - name: fetch /etc/host info
      shell: |
        awk -F: '{print $1}' /etc/hostname
      register: host_data

    - name: create write csv file
      local_action:
        module: lineinfile
        dest: /tmp/output.csv
        line: "users,host_data"
        create: yes

    - name: write remote host data to csv file
      local_action:
        module: lineinfile
        dest: /tmp/output.csv
        line: "{{ user_data.stdout }},{{ host_data.stdout }}"
        create: yes


Instead of using LINEINFILE, I think what you want is to copy content to a file with a couple of nested FOR commands to iterate your hosts and registered variables.

Also realize you could use pure ansible modules to do all of these tasks.  You could just use the read_csv module to read the passwd file. You could also use ansible_hostname or inventory_hostname variables instead of reading /etc/hostname. But even then you could just use the slurp to read the file if you really want the content of the file.

In general it is recommend to use dedicated, specific Ansible Modules instead of the generic shell module. In your case getent module – A wrapper to the Unix getent utility.
A minimal example playbook
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - getent:
      database: passwd
      split: ':'
    register: result

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ result.ansible_facts.getent_passwd.keys() }}"

  - debug:
      msg: |
        User;Hostname
        {% for user in result.ansible_facts.getent_passwd.keys() %}
        {{ user }};{{ inventory_hostname }}
        {% endfor %}

will produce the requested output.
TASK [debug] *******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - root
  - nobody
  - sshd
  - admin
...

TASK [debug] *******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: |-
    User;Hostname
    root;localhost
    nobody;localhost
    sshd;localhost
    admin;localhost
...

Writing it into a file is trivial then, in example via copy module - Parameter: content.
Similar Q&A

How to generate a CSV file with Jinja2 Template with dict elements in Ansible?


For completeness
---
- hosts: redhat
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - getent:
      database: passwd
      split: ':'
    register: result

  - local_action:
      module: copy
      dest: output.csv
      content: |
        User;Hostname
        {% for host in ansible_play_hosts %}
        {% for user in hostvars[host].result.ansible_facts.getent_passwd.keys() %}
        {{ user }};{{ host }}
        {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    run_once: true

